# Refreshing JTree contents

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using JTree to display channels and members on a network application.

What I wanted to ask is how should I handle the case where members move to different channels.
Should I create the tree again (generated from List some objects are other lists) or
I can do that dynamically(tree needs to be final to add listeners) .

Also how would each case affect the performance? The tree isn't huge something like 10 parents 10 leaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you can recreate and populate [JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) from its `Mode`l, descriptions about [DefaultTreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic), examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Catalog0240__Swing.htm)

2) all changes for GUI would be moved to the BackGround Task(s), please look at `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread` (most easiest way), but `Runnable#Thread` required wrapping all output (Swing methods) to the [invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: If I had a SwingWorker that would call the method to update the tree that should do the job right ?